# How to process Custom log data using Powershell?

Tags: powershell, data-processing

I have a log file which has data separated with "|" symbol. Like

```
"Username|servername|access|password|group"
"Username|servername|access|password|group"
```

I need to validate the data. And, If the group column(record) is missing information or empty. I need to write only that row into another file. Please help me. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `'Import-CSV` with `-Delimiter '|'`. If your file doesn't have a header line, you would also need to use `-Header` to define it. You could then use `Where` to filter for the empty Group lines and `Export-CSV` with `-Delimiter` again to create a new file of just those lines.

For example:

```
Import-CSV 'YourLog.log' -Delimiter '|' -Header 'Username','Servername','Access','Password','Group' |
    Where {$_.'Group' -eq ''} |
    Export-CSV 'EmptyGroupLines.log' -Delimiter '|'
```

Comment: Thank you for the Answer Mark, I will try and come back with my results.

Answer (score 3):

If you're just checking for missing data, you can run a quick check using a `regex` of '(\S+\|){4}\S+'.  Use `Get-Content` with the `-ReadCount` parameter, and you can work in batches of a few thousand records at a time, minimizing disk i/o and memory usage without going through them one record at a time.

```
Get-Content $inputfile -ReadCount 2000 |
foreach { 
          $_ -notmatch '(\S+\|){4}\S+' |
          Add-Content $outputfile
         }
```

Comment: Thank you for the Answer Miolinor, I will try and come back with my results.

Answer (score 0):

If your group column is always in the same place, which it looks like it is, you could use the split method. You can certainly neaten the code up. I have used the below as an example as to how you could use split.

The foreach statement is to iterate through each line in your file.
if (!$($groupstring.Split('|')[4])) checks if it is null.

```
$groupstring = 'Username|servername|access|password|group'
$groupstring.Split('|')[4]


foreach ($item in $collection)
{
    if (!$($groupstring.Split('|')[4])) 
    {
        Write-Host "variable is null" 
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.
Thanks, Tim.

Comment: Thank you for the Answer Tim, I will try and come back with my results.

Comment: No worries Subhantech. Looking at my answer, I didn't do an export of the whole line that you asked for. Mark Wragg and @mjoliner look like good answers.

Comment: No No Tim, I appreciate your answer. For me there is no sure Answer yet as I am validating all the possibilities. And, I am trying your solution too. Which is good. The first method i did was split method. That is why i didn't check your solutions immediately. I liked Mark's answer as it worked for me. But, there is a long way to go. As my script is a big one and I am learning all the possibilities. The Example i have given in question is just an Abstract of what i want.